# I Need divider for every column in dynamic table layout

Tags: java, android

I need table layout with divider For every column. I'm having eight text-view with fixed width for every row, Height is depends the web data, If one text-view can have more than thousand word another one  can have single word. text-view background is not filled for blank space, It's not helped me. I cannot find the solution for column divider. Can anyone please help me for column divider and sorry for my poor English.

```
// outer for loop
for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {

    final TableRow row = new TableRow(getActivity());
    row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    //      row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
    row.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    row.setWeightSum(10);

    // inner for loop
    for (int j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {

        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;
        final DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());
        final Login l = myDbHelper.getLogindb();
        // System.out.println(height + "\"" + width + "\"");
        final TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
        tv.setClickable(true);

        tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (float) 1.45)); 
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        tv.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xml drawable resource on the background field of every cell.

Example1:

drawable/cell_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape= "rectangle"  >
        <solid android:color="#000"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp"  android:color="#ff9"/>
</shape>
```

layout/table.xml

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/table" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>
            <TableLayout android:id="@+id/table_se" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_background" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_background" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_background" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView"></TextView>

                </TableRow>
</TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Example2:

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="*" android:background="#ff0000">
<TableRow android:background="#00ff00" android:layout_margin="2dip">
    <Button android:id="@+id/button" android:text="+" android:background="#0000ff" android:layout_margin="2dip"/>
    <TextView android:text="@string/label"  android:background="#0000ff" android:layout_margin="2dip"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/amount"  android:background="#0000ff" android:layout_margin="2dip"/>
</TableRow>
```

For more details : [Refer here](http://blog.intelligenia.com/2012/02/programacion-movil-en-android.html#more)

**Edit**

For column divider

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:stretchColumns="*"
  android:padding="5dip"
  android:divider="@drawable/tracking_green"
  android:showDividers="middle"
>
```

Comment: I need dynamic table layout, not static and also i edited my question i need column divider

Comment: @MathankumarK try this android:divider="@color/orangeBackground" Then you can define value at colors.xml like --- <color name="orangeBackground">#FF8000</color>

Comment: I tried using this  android:divider="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"  It's  better to send you the design but to upload image it's asking 10 reputation